# JQuery get html string inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i get text inside `a` ? eg. it will return "mice". Thanks

```
<ul id="animal">
    <li><a>cat</a></li>
    <li><a>mice</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As @mithun and @Dipesh answered, there is a difference between getting 'html' string and the 'content'. In your case if you just need the 'mice' then it is better to use `.text()`, if you also need the HTML tag (e.g. `<a>mice</a>`), then you should use `.html()`

Comment: Did you search "jquery get text of element."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.html()`

```
alert($('ul li a').html());
```

For alerting mice use below code,

```
alert($('ul li a:nth-child(2)').html());
```

**OR**

```
alert($('ul li a:eq(1)').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="animal">
    <li><a>cat</a></li>
    <li><a>mice</a></li>
</ul>
```

`$('#animal').find('a').eq(1).html()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfLi = $('#animal');
var lastLiText = listOfLi.children().last().text();
alert(lastLiText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="animal">
    <li><a>cat</a></li>
    <li><a>mice</a></li>
</ul>
```

using jquery.

```
$("#animal li a").eq(1).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <script>
>
>  $(document).ready(function() {
>
>         $( "ul li a" ).each(function( index ) {
>
>          alert( $(this).html() );
>          });
>         });
>
>    </script>
> ```